# Compare Execution Times of Two Functions

Tags: linux, shell-script, function, time

I am attempting to write a function which will take two commands as inputs, time the executions of both of them, then output those times to a text file.  After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux), I got most of the way there, and can write my execution times to a file one at a time.  The problem I have now is getting the function to accept two multi-word inputs.  My current code looks like:

```
timeDiff () {
  { time "$1" ; } 2> ~/file.txt
  { time "$2" ; } 2>> ~/file.txt
}
```

If I run these lines sequentially with the functions I want, everything is fine.  The file is overwritten with the time info of the two functions.  Here are some of the attempts and problems I have with this:

> ```
> timeDiff grep "str" file1 query database lookup.sql
> ```

This will cause my file to have a warning on grep, some times, and a `bash: str: command not found`.

> ```
> timeDiff 'grep "str" file1' 'query database lookup.sql'
> ```

This will cause my file to have bash:grep "str" file1: No such file or directory, some times, and bash:query database lookup.sql: No such file or directory.

I think that this is related to how I need quotation marks for my grep, but perhaps there's a better way of writing the inputs for the functions.  I'm a beginner, so I'm eager to learn!  Thanks!

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

> ```
>  { time "$1" ; } 2> ~/file.txt
> ```

With a shell such as `bash` that has `time` as a keyword, you're using the `time` keyword to time the evaluation of the `"$1"` shell code. `"$1"` is code that executes the command whose name is in the first position parameter to the function:

With:

> ```
> timeDiff grep "str" file1 query database lookup.sql
> ```

You're invoking `timeDiff` with `grep` as first argument and `str` as second argument (and `file1` as third, etc.)

So `time "$1"` will time the execution of the command called `grep` without argument. `grep` requires at least one argument so will complain.

In

> ```
> timeDiff 'grep "str" file1' 'query database lookup.sql'
> ```

This time `$1` will be `grep "str" file1` but it's very unlikely there's a command by that name.

What it looks like you want is to time the evaluation of shell code passed in the first and second arguments like:

```
timeDiff () {
  time eval " $1"
  time eval " $2"
} 2> ~/file.txt
```

Or possibly:

```
timeDiff () {
  eval "time {
    $1
  }"
  eval "time {
    $2
  }
} 2> ~/file.txt
```

To evaluate shell code consisting of:

```
time {
  contents-of-$1
}
```

To time the command group whose body is the contents of the first position argument.

Also beware that in:

```
{ time cmd; } 2> file
```

The timing will end-up in `file`, but also the errors of `cmd` (and the errors of the shell failing to run `cmd` if any).

To get *only* the timing in `file`, you'd need something like:

```
{ time cmd 2>&3 3>&-; } 3>&2 2> file
```

Comment: Excellent, your first rewrite recommendation did exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
timeDiff grep "str" file1 query database lookup.sql
```

will make $1=grep and $2=str

```
timeDiff 'grep "str" file1' 'query database lookup.sql'
```

will make $1 the string "grep "str" file1"  so it looks for a file called

```
./grep_"str"_file1
```

Where the _ are space characters: there is no such file.

You need to use bash's *eval* function to turn a string into an executable command line statement.

But be careful they say "eval is evil" for a reason :)

Comment: It looks for a file called `grep "str" file1` in `$PATH`, not in the current working directory (unless `$PATH` contains a `.` or empty string element which would be a bad idea).